# Passivity and stability

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I read the paper "Bilateral Control of Teleoperators with Time Delay",which is written by Robert J. Anderson and Mark W. Spong. In that paper, they defined passivity of an n-port flow as
$\int^\infty_0 F^T (t) v(t) dt \geqslant 0$
$F$ means effort and $v$ means flow.
And they said if a two-port system is passive, the system is stable. They didn't said that directly, but they said an system can be unstable by being nonpassive. They said that without proof, so I want to know why an passive system is stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the entire paper but only checked the statement you mentioned.

> The two-port communication circuit for this system is nonpassive, and is the cause of the instability.

And later they write again

> [...] it was shown that the instability [...] is due to a nonpassive communication block.

It looks to me like you mixed up sufficient and necessary conditions here.
They write in the paper, as you already mentioned in your question, that *nonpassive* implies *unstable*.

This makes passivity a **necessary** condition for stability in this case.

They did **not** say that it is a **sufficient** condition, which would be how you understood it, that *passive* implies *stable*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Sufficiency) explains it a bit more compact than me.

> If P is sufficient for Q, then knowing P to be true is adequate grounds to conclude that Q is true; however, knowing P to be false does not meet a minimal need to conclude that Q is false.

I hope I could explain it somewhat understandable, don't hesitate to comment if not.

Comment: So that means if a system is stable, that is passive because passivity is a necessary condition. And and passive system is not always stable. I was confused about that before your answer.
How can I proof "An stable system is passive"? Could you give me some informations or references to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have references about that proof, but there are probably a lot of papers out there that include it. Maybe you also find something among the references of the paper that you mentioned in your question